# How to attach PCV breather hose on MkIII Golf?

Tags: vw, engine

The old "breather hose" on my Mk3 VW Golf became cracked and fell off.  I bought a replacement tube, which connects to part of the PCV apparatus on top of the engine via a hose clamp, but it is not clear how it is meant to attach at the bottom of the engine.  There must be some kind of clip that I need -- how can I find the part number and order it?

Here is a photo of the engine compartment, with the tube in question outlined in red:
[image]

And here is a close-up of where it should connect to the engine at the bottom:
[image]

**How should the tube be secured?**

Comment: Yeah, we need a picture of the part at the bottom of the engine. In most cases, the hose from the PCV valve actually connects to the air intake somewhere. The PCV valve vents excess pressure, so that air is reused by the engine, not typically anything at the *bottom* of the engine.

Comment: Photos have been added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer [on VWVortex](http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?5227128-How-to-attach-breather-hose-to-crankcase)!  What is needed is the small clip listed here: http://www.germanautoparts.com/Volkswagen/Golf/Engine/310/2